# Ubuntu 15.04 & ultrawide monitor. How to set max resolution?

Tags: 15.04, display, display-resolution

I am trying to set up Ubuntu 15.04 on an Intel nuc5i5ryh with an ASUS mx299Q monitor. It is connected with a miniDisplayPort to DVIcable. 
It is supposed to support 2560x1080 21:9 ultrawide resolution.

Ubuntu does not show any options for 21:9 and most I can get is 1680x1050 (16:10)

Is there some way to increase the resolution with commandline "trickery"?
Or some tool or package that would be helpful?

Thank you.

(edit, info from xrandr,cvt and trying to adjust:)

```
torost@torost-desktop:~$ xrandr
Screen 0: minimum 8 x 8, current 1680 x 1050, maximum 32767 x 32767
DP1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI2 connected primary 1680x1050+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 673mm x 284mm
   1680x1050      59.9* 
   1280x1024      75.0     60.0  
   1440x900       59.9  
   1280x960       60.0  
   1280x800       59.9  
   1152x864       75.0  
   1280x720       60.0  
   1024x768       75.1     70.1     60.0  
   832x624        74.6  
   800x600        72.2     75.0     60.3     56.2  
   640x480        75.0     66.7     60.0  
   720x400        70.1  
VIRTUAL1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
```

running cvt:

```
$ cvt 2560 1080 60
# 2560x1080 59.98 Hz (CVT) hsync: 67.17 kHz; pclk: 230.00 MHz
Modeline "2560x1080_60.00"  230.00  2560 2720 2992 3424  1080 1083 1093 1120 -hsync +vsync 

$ xrandr --newmode "2560x1080_60.00" 230.00  2560 2720 2992 3424  1080 1083 1093 1120 -hsync +vsync

$ xrandr --output HDMI2 --mode 2560x1080_60.00
```

edit: after playing with xrandr I managed to up the resolution. 
The screen complains "Cable incorrect. Please use dual link DVI cable"
Not sure what resolution I am actually getting, but it is a great improvement.

My intial minihdmi-hdmi cable did not work, so used this adapter to get from minidisplayport to dvi-dvi.

Working on making this setting permanent now. :D

edit2: I got it to work, posting solution for making it permanent below, incase anyone else stumbles upon this problem. After the solution below, restart and chose the new resolution from the monitorsettings.

Had to create an etc/X11/xorg.conf , oddly enough there was no file there.
it looks like this:

```
Section "Monitor"
    Identifier "HDMI2"
    Modeline "2560x1080" 230.00  2560 2720 2992 3424  1080 1083 1093 1120 -hsync +vsync
    Option "PreferredMode" "2560x1080"
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier "Screen0"
    Monitor "HDMI2"
    DefaultDepth 24
    SubSection "Display"
        Modes "2560x1080"
    EndSubSection
EndSection

Section "Device"
    Identifier "Device0"
    Driver "intel"
EndSection
```

Comment: can you post the output of  `xrandr` ?, i guess it should match the GUI options, but maybe it can give you more modes.

Comment: do not edit to say it is solved. Instead, [edit] and move the solution to an answer, so others can benefit from it.